# Representing large chunk of text as key in Hadoop

Tags: java, string, hash, hadoop

I am using Hadoop map-reduce program, where I want to represent part of the file as key. This I want to use to do for some analytics. However I found this has brought the performance. Can anyone please tell if there are any alternative to using large chunk of text. Can we encode it in any other format. I have also found by converting strings to byte or binary format. But still I am not able to store it in integer datatype. I tried converting it to BigInteger but in vain, since there are also collisions happening when reducing the text which are not similar. How to represent large chunk of text as key in mapper other than using Text datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long can the part of your file be? How similar are the keys to each other? Have you considered using the MD5 hash (or similar) of the text as the key in your mapper?

Comment: Thank for your kind response. After using MD5 signature to represent text, now the size is reduce 32 characters. Is it a good approach to use integer for representing all the alphabets in the alphanumeric signature, even further reducing all the text to integer type. Can we use this as a common practice. If so after converting the string to integer type, is it good to represent the integer in the form of Big Integer, Big Decimal in Hadoop. One form of Big Decimal is implemented in Hadoop example program for calculating PI.

Comment: MD5 hashes are alphanumerical. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to know if we can convert all the alphanumeric characters generated from MD5 signatures to further numbers only for all a-z characters in it and store it in Bigdecimal or Biginteger datatype.

Comment: MD5 hashes have a fixed-length of 32 chars (128 bits). Still you could replace the chars [a-z] with a single number from 0-26 or their decimal ascii code. You have to evaluate for yourself if this is necessary and whether it leads to promising results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look at it. I will also try to evaluate it with Perl or Python and see the performance just for comparison purpose.